# Inverse Problems in Finance

Tags: reference-request, parameter-estimation, dynamic

Are there any canonical references for inverse problems in finance?  For example, if I have a measure that evolves with Fokker-Planck dynamics, are there standard approaches used by the community to recover the parameters of the drift and diffusion components of the dynamics?  These could also be mathematical resources that are commonly used by those in finance.

Comment: http://www.cmap.polytechnique.fr/~rama/teaching/princeton.html